# Error getting raster symbology property

Tags: arcpy, symbology

I get this error when I run my script:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "", line 1, in  AttributeError: 'Symbology' object has no attribute 'renderer'

Script:

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = p.listMaps('Map')[0]
l = m.listLayers('Raster1')[0]
sym = l.symbology
sym.renderer
```

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/symbology-class.htm

According to this URL's page there shouldn't be any error.

Comment: @BERA that looks like it could easily be made into an answer that I would upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Accourding to the [help section for symbology class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/symbology-class.htm):

> It is important to first make sure that a layer supports a renderer or
>   colorizer and to know its type before trying to make updates to it.
>   The built in hasattr function can be used for this purpose.

```
hasattr(l, 'renderer')
False
```

So renderer might not be supported for your raster layer.

What are you trying to do with the raster symbology? Maybe some other method is supported which you can use.